# CSS trouble with Pretty URLs

Tags: .htaccess

I have an index.php, profile.php files in localhost/project
I've written following code in my .htaccess file to have **localhost/project/profile.php?u=sam** by visiting **localhost/project/sam**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1
```

When I visit **http://localhost/project/sam** it diplays what I want without errors. But when I visit **http://localhost/project/sam/** (with trailing **/** ) it displays the page with plain text, that means the css file is not attached.

Anyone know the reason for this? And help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using relative URI paths to reference those external resources. And relative URIs are resolved on a base URI that is the URI of the current document if not specified otherwise.

So when using a relative URI path like `css/style.css` on `/project/sam` it is resolved to `/project/css/style.css`; but when used on `/project/sam/` it is resolved to `/project/sam/css/style.css`.

You could fix this by either using the absolute URI path `/project/css/style.css` or by changing the base URI with the [`BASE` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE). But note that the latter will affect *all* relative URIs and not just relative URI paths.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a relative link to your css.

Comment: yes. my css files are in "styles" folder and I've called them as 'styles/style.css'. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

How do you include that css file? If you generate the path from PHP, it might contain a double '/' if your request contains a trailing '/'. Please check your HTML output and moidify the path of the CSS.

Comment: I've included CSS like this <link href="./styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0):

Either require the slash, or forbid it, or you'll never know whether relative links need to go uplevel or not. For example to forbid the slash:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R]
```

which will redirect the client to the same page without the slash included. It's best to have a single canonical URI for an object anyway.

Comment: thanks, but my folder is located at C:\wamp\www\project So when I add this line to .htaccess file, when I visited the URI with trailing slash, it redirects to a page http://localhost/C:\wamp\www\project\.... which doesnot exist.